# How to print a webpage with window.print

Tags: javascript

I need to remove the footer and header from a webpage and show only the content. 
I did this, but in the page, URL and date are displayed, how to remove them?

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.print()" value="Print"/>
```

And `window.print()` function generates a file with the extension *.xps*. There is a way to without generate this file, just open a window and do print.

Comment: That is the printer settings, JavaScript has no control over that.

Answer (score -2):

Create an hidden iFrame, insert the content what you need and then call `print()` on the frame. Otherwise you can use an `jQuery` plugin.

XPS file? Install/select your printer!